# Multi-user Rails blogging-type site - which CMS / solution?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, content-management-system, structure

I apologize if the question seems a bit too general, but I have spent some time thinking on how to model this kind of site and I guess some input would be really helpful.

I need to create a multiuser site with blog functionality - people uploading media, social component. It was fairly easy to prototype the thing with paperclip and minimal functionality, but when it comes to storing more content number of solutions is growing..

Would that be a generally good idea to use something like RefineryCMS (seems to be most up-to-date with current Rails) with access to dashboard granted to users that create pages. Would users be able to manage separate pages through RefineryCMS?

What if there are several types of pages (like blog / portfolio), that have different functionality - would one CMS be able to handle the variation?

Answer (score 0):

I would advise Wordpress, perhaps a MU install; it is PHP based as opposed to Rails, however has much better support and has a tendency to just work. You can hack it and modify it as you please, or use plugins and themes, pre or self made. It has the media aspect you desire, along with users and roles; it can be used with Buddypress for the social aspect. If you install [P2 Reloaded](http://p2reloaded.com/) (theme) on one of your multi-sites (if you chose to use MU) you will even be able to have a microblogging aspect to it. I commerically design websites, and almost always Wordpress is the first tool I use, almost like the Swiss Army Knives of CMS.
https://wordpress.org

Comment: If you're going to go this way, you definitely want to add BuddyPress.